# How to specify storage class specifier for an object of struct without a name?

Tags: c, struct, storage-class-specifier

I am using a struct like:

```
struct{
    int a;
    char b[100];
}name;
```

I want to use `static` storage class specifier on `name`.
How can I do that?

Comment: I have added it as an answer, we shall not answer a question with a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the word `static` in front of it:

```
static struct{
    int a;
    char b[100];
} name;
```

This will declare a variable named `name` with the type `struct { ... }` and the storage class specifier `static`.

To initialize the member of the `struct`, you can use

```
static struct{
    int a;
    char b[100];
} name = {5};
```

Comment: The declaration works, but when I use `name` like `name.a = 1`, it shows error saying `unknown type name ‘name’`. Also, I am doing this globally.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/M9KatR Can you make a full example?

Comment: `name.a = 5;` can only be in a function. Do you want to initialize it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize a structure members having `static` storage in file scope, you can do something like

```
static struct{
    int a;
    char b[100];
} name = {.a=5, .b = "test1"};
```